# Result of .join in dask dataframes seems to depend on the way, the dask dataframe was generated

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I got unexpected results when applying `join` to dask dataframes which were generated by the .from_delayed method. I want to demonstrate this by the following example, which consists of three parts.

1. Generate dask dataframe via the `from_delayed` method and join it with a dask dataframe generated via `from_pandas`
2. Convert both dataframes to pandas dataframes with the `compute` method. Joined them as in (1)
3. Convert the dask dataframe, which is generated via `from_delayed` method to pandas using `compute`. Aferwards convert it back to dask using `from_pandas`. Then join as in (1).

Consider the following code:

```
import dask.dataframe
import pandas as pd

# functions for generating a dask dataframe
def get_pdf(character):
    '''constructs a pandas dataframe with indexes [character]1, ..., [character]5'''
    index = [character + str(i) for i in range(5)]
    return pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5]}, index = index)

def get_ddf():
    '''constructs dask dataframe out of pandas dataframes via the .from-delayed method with indexes A1, A2, A3, ... F3, F3, F4'''
    delayed_list = [dask.delayed(get_pdf)(x) for x in 'ABCDEF']  
    return dask.dataframe.from_delayed(delayed_list)

#generate dask dataframes, that will be joined
ddf1 = get_ddf()
ddf2 = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'B': [1,2,3]}, index = ['A0', 'B1', 'C3']), npartitions = 2)

#recreate ddf1 by converting it to a pandas dataframe and afterwards to a dask dataframe
ddf1_from_pandas = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(ddf1.compute(), npartitions = 3)

#compute joins
dask_from_delayed_join = ddf1.join(ddf2, how = 'inner')
pandas_join = ddf1.compute().join(ddf2.compute(), how = 'inner')
dask_from_pandas_join = ddf1_from_pandas.join(ddf2, how = 'inner')
```

I would expect all three results (`dask_from_delayed_join`, `pandas_join`, `dask_from_pandas_join`) to be the same.

However, the first result differs from the others:

`print(dask_from_delayed_join.compute())`:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
```

`print(pandas_join)`:

```
    A  B
A0  1  1
B1  2  2
C3  4  3
```

`print(dask_from_pandas_join.compute())`:

```
    A  B
A0  1  1
B1  2  2
C3  4  3
```

What is going on?

Comment: I'm looking into this now btw.  Hope to have an answer within a day or three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were indeed some issues with `dd.merge`.  These have been resolved in dask version 0.10.2

```
In [10]: print(dask_from_delayed_join.compute())
    A  B
A0  1  1
B1  2  2
C3  4  3

In [11]: print(pandas_join)
    A  B
A0  1  1
B1  2  2
C3  4  3

In [12]: print(dask_from_pandas_join.compute())
    A  B
A0  1  1
B1  2  2
C3  4  3
```